# Catch scan of external barcode scanner while app not running

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth

Currently I'm writing an application which will work with external barcode scanners over Bluethooth. I'm currently trying several different scanners and it seems they all simulate keyboard input if they scan a code. But now I've found a [Socket Mobile](http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/HGSY2ZM/A/socket-mobile-chs-7xi-2d-bluetooth-barcode-scanner?fnode=0fbd2107c3a4364e84f5e0a9751e41cc13b20ad5beca0dba70f3d14655af9660fc29692e2f52e30ee41cb8c8736bd3678d1ebcb32d256aa9755bb3ace4f43afa487116708dfee1036b23f366a1c05b34ad88a8f3b5a9a0796c149a574bccb0be) scanner, which is certificated by apple and delivers a SDK.

What I need is a way to scan a code while the iPhone is in my pocket without the display unlocked (maybe in background if thats possible?).

So I want to know if it's even possible what I'm trying and if it is, can I achieve this with a Keyboard simulation or is the SDK thing a better way?

I would like to post some code at this point, but I've absolutely no idea where to start and I try to find something on google for 2 days now.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes. This is totally possible if you are using BLE. I have done it. You can set it up so that your application connects to the device and when the device wants to, it can send a message and your application in the background will respond.

Comment: @ryantxr sound good, do you have any link where i can start because i cant find anything yet?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/bluetooth/

Comment: @ryantxr okay thank you i'll start reading then. Does every bluethooth scanner supports BLE these days? Guess not, because I can't find any on google which explicit say "I support ble"!?

Comment: It is also known as Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) or Bluetooth 4 or Bluetooth Smart.  They are all the same thing.

Comment: @ryantxr Yea thanks I already know what BLE is ;). I jut can't find any 2D-Scanner with BT 4.0 :D